# How to override nullable field with non-nullable one dart

Tags: dart, inheritance, dart-null-safety

I have a class with a nullable property. I would like to make a superclass that overrides that property with a non nullable one

so

```
class Example {
String? name;
}

class NamedExample extends Example {
@override
String name;

}
```

Is there some way to do that? if not how is this goal conventionally accomplished.

I basically want two identical classes except one of them always has a property while it is optional in another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a place for the `covariant` keyword. Normally it does not make sense to override a parameter's type with its subtype and it is invalid to do so. This keyword tells the analyzer this is intentional. It can be added in either the super or subclass.

Subclass:

```dart
class Example {
  String? name;
}

class NamedExample extends Example {
  @override
  covariant String name;
  
  NamedExample(this.name);
}
```

Superclass:

```dart
class Example {
  covariant String? name;
}

class NamedExample extends Example {
  @override
  String name;
  
  NamedExample(this.name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you can't override the `String? name` member with `String name` is because it can violate the contract of the setter in the base class and therefore could be unsafe.  The base class advertises that:

```dart
var example = Example();
example.name = null;
```

is legal.  However, if `example` instead is an instance of `NamedExample`, the `example.name = null` assignment would no longer be legal.  The `covariant` keyword disables this safety check and trusts that you will never perform such an assignment in practice.

In general, you should [avoid overriding fields](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/overridden_fields.html).

You *could* safely have the override if your classes expose only a getter.  Both of the following examples would be legal and safe:

```dart
class Example {
  String? _optionalName;
  String? get name => _optionalName;
}

class NamedExample extends Example {
  NamedExample(this._requiredName);

  String _requiredName;

  @override
  String get name => _requiredName;
}
```

or

```dart
class Example {
  Example([this.name]);

  final String? name;
}

class NamedExample extends Example {
  NamedExample(this.name);

  @override
  final String name;
}
```

Comment: Oh. I didn’t look up the covariant keyword. I thought it was specifically for overriding with a different type. I didn’t realize it permitted different assignments in every case. I won’t want that. This is a much better solution. Thank you

Comment: Oh. Read about it just now. It is specifically for overriding in a subtype. I guess I misunderstood what you were saying. Your solution still seems like the better way though